# Modify or delete the display attribute value of a textarea tag with JS

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

I'm automating a web form with Python 3.8.0 and Selenium 3.141

I have a tag, textarea, that I can access via an id or name. I have a style attribute I'm trying to remove or modify called "display", which is currently set to "none". I would prefer to remove it entirely or set it to "block" so I can access it with Selenium.

The javascript I'm trying to use is

```
document.querySelector("textarea[id='id']").removeAttribute("display");
```

which, for selenium, I'm executing with

```
driver.execute_script("""document.querySelector("textarea[id='id']").removeAttribute("display");""")
```

Unfortunately, when the page loads, I don't see the expected result (compared to manually deleting display:none with inspect element). Since the texarea box is hidden, Selenium throws an `is not reachable by keyboard` error when I try to send keys into the textarea.

My JS code doesn't throw any errors, but I still believe it's malformed. I am not familiar enough with the CSS selector code or JS in general to know where I've gone wrong and would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `removeAttribute` removes HTML attribute, not CSS. You need to use `element.style.display = "block";`